# PHP convert this timestamp to epoch/unix time (int)

Tags: php, datetime

Hi Guys I'm looking to convert this type of datetime-stamp to unix/epoch time in php

```
2019-08-10D00:00:03.712125000
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP DateTime can only work with 4 digits after the decimal point. So one alternative for you can be to ignore that part to begin with, then - if applicable - append it back to the final timestamp. Keep in mind though, that this can cause issues further down the line.

```
$string = "2019-08-10D00:00:03.712125000";
$parts = explode(".", $string);
$microseconds = $parts[1];

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\DH:i:s", $parts[0]);
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();

// If you want to round it to 4 decimal places
// $microseconds = ltrim(round("0.".$microseconds, 4), "0.");

// If you want to append the microseconds back for whichever reason
// $timestamp .= ".".$microseconds;

echo $timestamp;
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/8hqmr